# Mobile app. load testing using jmeter

Tags: android, jmeter, performance-testing

I have configure everything and doing android app testing using jmeter. As a Http request I am getting only web services and jmeter puts load on those. So is that correct mobile app load testing??

I am recording scenario and then putting load. If I do signup , login or any action , it creating web service request only so I am little bit confuse what am I doing right app testing or not?

Is this read testing of mobile app testing to put load on web services only?

Please see attached screenshot of recent recorded plan.[image]

Comment: Yes, this is the right way for load testing. Actual load will be on web-services and not on app, so if there is any issue in the app that should be uncovered during functional testing.

Comment: @JmeterPerfTest - Thanks for reply. Any more variation which I can apply to my load test plan to check actual strength of my mobile app? I mean web service.

Comment: you can make it replicate the actual user experience by adding delays for each request. Generally actual users never finish the activity from login to logout in a matter of seconds. otherwise also this test will give you the performance of the application/servers.

Answer (score -2):

JMeter can be used for mobile performance testing along with the desktop web application. ... In order to configure JMeter and mobile device to record scripts for native app in JMeter for android and iOS platforms, you can refer the steps mentioned below. It's just similar to recording scripts for web applications.

Comment: What steps are you refering to? Please provide a link or be more specific. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: Please provide the steps.